# Copying random values to OpenCL device returns non valid values

Tags: python, opencl, gpgpu, pyopencl

I have a simple problem where I want to copy randomly generated floats on an OpenCL device and use those values on the device because `OpenCL` doesn't provide a random number generator.

However, it seems that the values cannot get properly used when on the device. The values returned to `HOST_result` are not the initially generated value, they are just probably older values that were onto the memory space.

Here is a minimally-non-working example. I would require someone to point out what is wrong with this code.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

kernelSource = """

__kernel void testKernel(__global float *result, __global float *randomNum)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    result[gid] = randomNum[gid];
}

"""

context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)
device = context.devices[0]
program = cl.Program(context, kernelSource).build()

N = 4

HOST_result = np.ones(N, dtype=cl.cltypes.float)
print(HOST_result.shape)
DEVICE_result = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=HOST_result)

HOST_rand = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=N)
print(HOST_rand.shape)
HOST_rand.astype(cl.cltypes.float)
DEVICE_rand = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=HOST_rand)

program.testKernel(queue, HOST_result.shape, None, DEVICE_result, DEVICE_rand)
queue.finish()
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dest=HOST_result, src=DEVICE_result)

print(HOST_rand)
print(HOST_result)


"""
Using cl.Buffer() with the COPY_HOST_PTR flag, the host buffer is copied to the device buffer and it allocates memory
the size of the buffer where HOST_PTR points to.
"""
```

The outputs are

```
(4,)
(4,)
[0.02692256 0.82201746 0.05025519 0.31266968]
[-6.9784595e-12  1.2153804e+00 -2.4271645e-30  1.8305043e+00]
```

This error does not happen if we change the `HOST_rand` to `HOST_rand = np.zeros(N, dtype=cl.cltypes.float)`. All the values at the end become `[0, 0, 0, 0]` as expected. Any `np.array([])` seems to work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, `HOST_rand.astype(cl.cltypes.float)` changes the type, but not the memory alignment.

Thus, because my functions use `float32`, the values are read wrong on the `OpenCL` device.

To remedy the situation, it is possible to use `numpy` [generator objects](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.random.html). This object allows to pass more parameters for the random values generation.
We get the default `Generator`, then we pass the correct type.

```
rndGenerator = np.random.default_rng()
HOST_rand = rndGenerator.random(size=N, dtype=cl.cltypes.float)
```

Now the values are correctly read on the device.